# Smoothing looks different than system's, when using NSString drawAtPoint:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, drawing, smoothing

I have a custom status item view where I draw a string using `NSString`'s `drawAtPoint:withAttributes:`. When comparing to the system clock with the same text, it seems that my text is missing subpixel smoothing and looks sort of grainy. I found an advice to shift drawing point from (x,y) to (x+0.5,y+0.5), but it did not help. Default view and `setTitle:` produce the same result.

That's how it looks:

[image]

Seems that system clock has some light gray border below, but I could not imitate it by drawing a string the second time with light gray color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any "font smoothing" in the system's rendering, or in any menu titles on my machine.  If it was turned on, you'd see red and blue tinted pixels at the edges of the characters, instead of just gray. The difference is quite obvious when zoomed in.

You may want to experiment with turning subpixel positioning and quantization on or off, using 
[`CGContextSetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts), [`CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts), etc.

Otherwise, the main difference really is that faint white shadow in the system's rendering. Try [setting the context's shadow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetShadowWithColor) to an offset of {0,1} (or maybe {0,-1} if your context is flipped?), blur of 0 or 1, and a color of 100% white at 30% alpha -- that looks pretty close to me.

Comment: Thanks, Kurt. It still does not look exactly like system text, but it is definitely much better. I guess it is the best that can be done without looking into OSX source code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(<#CGSize size#>);
```

for context initialization. On retina displays it leads to blured renderings of fonts. Use

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myFrameSize, NO, 0.0f);
```

instead to fix it.

Also, it seems if you use a Layer, set yourself as the layer delegate and do your drawing in:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSGraphicsContext *nsGraphicsContext;
    nsGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx
                                                                   flipped:NO];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nsGraphicsContext];

    // drawing here...

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

It will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CGContextRef  ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort;
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(ctx, true);
```

I was searching for that a long time, too. Got it from a WWDC video (I think it was "Best Practices for Cocoa Animation")